# Ubuntu 2 Node Cluster Postgresql 9.3 with pacemaker and Streaming Replication

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, ubuntu-14.04, failover, pacemaker

I'm trying to setup a 2 Node Cluster with Postresql 9.3 and Streaming Replication. 
Streaming Replication is successfully configured. Master is listen up and is sending to slave. I can do failover manually with creating the trigger file and failback master by update data directory with rsync, promote old master as slave an failover again.

At this point, all is working fine.

Now I wanna setup automatic failover with virtual (floating) IP with pacemaker. The master always should have the VIP to accept client connections for read and writes. If the postgresql service who is master goes down, an failover should triggered an the floating IP should moved to slave (new master)

I try it by following configuration guides 
https://github.com/t-matsuo/resource-agents/wiki/Resource-Agent-for-PostgreSQL-9.1-streaming-replication
https://github.com/t-matsuo/resource-agents/wiki
but unfortunately postgres is not started by pacemaker and only the vip-master is assigned to first started host.

My Pacemaker Configuration is:

```
property \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
    stonith-enabled="false" \
    crmd-transition-delay="0s"


primitive pgsql ocf:heartbeat:pgsql \
    params \
        pgctl="/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster" \
        psql="/usr/bin/psql" \
        pgdata="/database/postgresql/9.3/main/" \
        start_opt="-p 5432" \
        rep_mode="sync" \
        node_list="robin marshall" \
        restore_command="" \
        primary_conninfo_opt="keepalives_idle=60 keepalives_interval=5 keepalives_count=5" \
        master_ip="172.16.1.1" \
        stop_escalate="0" \
    op start   timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="restart" \
    op monitor timeout="60s" interval="5s" on-fail="restart" \
    op monitor timeout="60s" interval="2s"  on-fail="restart" role="Master" \
    op promote timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="restart" \
    op demote  timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="stop" \
    op stop    timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="block" \
    op notify  timeout="60s" interval="0s"

primitive pingCheck ocf:pacemaker:ping \
    params \
        name="default_ping_set" \
        host_list="172.16.0.1" \
        multiplier="100" \
    op start   timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="restart" \
    op monitor timeout="60s" interval="2s" on-fail="restart" \
    op stop    timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="ignore"


rsc_defaults \
    resource-stickiness="INFINITY" \
    migration-threshold="1"

ms msPostgresql pgsql \
    meta \
        master-max="1" \
        master-node-max="1" \
        clone-max="2" \
        clone-node-max="1" \
        notify="true"


primitive vip-master ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
    params \
        ip="172.16.1.1" \
        nic="bond0" \
        cidr_netmask="16" \
    op start   timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="stop" \
    op monitor timeout="60s" interval="2s" on-fail="restart" \
    op stop    timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="block"


primitive vip-slave ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
    params \
        ip="172.16.1.2" \
        nic="bond0" \
        cidr_netmask="16" \
    meta \
        resource-stickiness="1" \
    op start   timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="restart" \
    op monitor timeout="60s" interval="2s" on-fail="restart" \
    op stop    timeout="60s" interval="0s"  on-fail="block"


clone clnPingCheck pingCheck
group master-group \
      vip-master \
      vip-rep 

location rsc_location-1 vip-slave \
    rule  200: pgsql-status eq "HS:sync" \
    rule  100: pgsql-status eq "PRI" \
    rule  -inf: not_defined pgsql-status \
    rule  -inf: pgsql-status ne "HS:sync" and pgsql-status ne "PRI"


location rsc_location-2 msPostgresql \
    rule -inf: not_defined default_ping_set or default_ping_set lt 100

colocation rsc_colocation-1 inf: msPostgresql        clnPingCheck
colocation rsc_colocation-2 inf: master-group        msPostgresql:Master

order rsc_order-1 0: clnPingCheck          msPostgresql
order rsc_order-2 0: msPostgresql:promote  master-group:start   symmetrical=false
order rsc_order-3 0: msPostgresql:demote   master-group:stop    symmetrical=false
```

The crm_mom -A console show me the following:

```
Last updated: Wed Oct 29 20:02:32 2014
Last change: Wed Oct 29 19:51:36 2014 via crm_attribute on robin
Stack: corosync
Current DC: robin (739246346) - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.10-42f2063
2 Nodes configured
7 Resources configured


Online: [ robin ]
OFFLINE: [ marshall ]

vip-master      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started robin
 Clone Set: clnPingCheck [pingCheck]
     Started: [ robin ]
     Stopped: [ marshall ]

Node Attributes:
* Node robin:
    + default_ping_set                  : 100
    + pgsql-data-status                 : LATEST    

Failed actions:
    pgsql_start_0 (node=robin, call=48, rc=5, status=complete, last-rc-change=Wed Oct 29 20:01:48 2014
, queued=19ms, exec=0ms
): not installed
```

I look in the syslog and see, that psql has any problems, but I can not guess what it is.

```
Oct 29 20:00:40 robin crmd[14139]:  warning: do_log: FSA: Input I_DC_TIMEOUT from crm_timer_popped() received in state S_PENDING
Oct 29 20:00:41 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: INFO: Configuration file is /database/postgresql/9.3/main//postgresql.conf not readable during probe.
Oct 29 20:00:41 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: INFO: Don't check /database/postgresql/9.3/main/ during probe
Oct 29 20:00:42 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: INFO: Changing pgsql-data-status on  : ->LATEST.
Oct 29 20:00:42 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86400). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:43 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86399). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:44 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86398). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:45 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86397). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:46 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86396). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:47 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86395). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:48 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86394). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:49 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86393). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:51 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86392). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:52 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86391). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:53 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86390). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:54 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86389). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:55 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86388). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:56 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86387). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:57 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86386). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:58 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86385). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:00:59 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86384). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:00 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86383). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:02 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86382). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:03 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86381). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:04 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86380). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:05 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86379). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:06 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86378). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:07 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86377). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:08 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86376). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:09 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86375). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:10 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86374). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:12 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86373). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:13 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86372). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:14 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86371). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:15 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86370). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:16 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86369). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:17 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86368). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:18 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86367). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:19 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86366). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:20 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86365). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:22 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86364). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:23 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86363). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:24 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86362). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:25 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86361). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:26 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86360). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:27 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86359). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:28 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86358). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:29 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86357). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:30 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86356). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:32 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86355). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:33 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86354). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:34 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86353). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:35 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86352). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:36 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86351). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:37 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86350). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:38 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86349). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:39 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86348). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:40 robin pgsql(pgsql)[14148]: WARNING: Retrying(remain 86347). "exec_with_timeout 0 /usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l forever -N -n pgsql-data-status -v LATEST" failed. rc=22. stdout="non-option ARGV-elements: pgsql-data-status #012Please choose from one of the matches above and suppy the 'id' with --attr-id".
Oct 29 20:01:41 robin lrmd[14136]:  warning: child_timeout_callback: pgsql_monitor_0 process (PID 14148) timed out
Oct 29 20:01:41 robin lrmd[14136]:  warning: operation_finished: pgsql_monitor_0:14148 - timed out after 60000ms
Oct 29 20:01:41 robin crmd[14139]:    error: process_lrm_event: LRM operation pgsql_monitor_0 (10) Timed Out (timeout=60000ms)
Oct 29 20:01:41 robin crmd[14139]:  warning: status_from_rc: Action 5 (pgsql:0_monitor_0) on robin failed (target: 7 vs. rc: 1): Error
Oct 29 20:01:41 robin pengine[14138]:  warning: unpack_rsc_op: Processing failed op monitor for pgsql:0 on robin: unknown error (1)
Oct 29 20:01:41 robin IPaddr2(vip-master)[14821]: INFO: Adding IPv4 address 172.16.1.1/16 with broadcast address 172.16.255.255 to device bond0
Oct 29 20:01:41 robin IPaddr2(vip-master)[14821]: INFO: Bringing device bond0 up
Oct 29 20:01:41 robin IPaddr2(vip-master)[14821]: INFO: /usr/lib/heartbeat/send_arp -i 200 -r 5 -p /var/run/resource-agents/send_arp-172.16.1.1 bond0 172.16.1.1 auto not_used not_used
Oct 29 20:01:48 robin pengine[14138]:  warning: unpack_rsc_op: Processing failed op monitor for pgsql:0 on robin: unknown error (1)
Oct 29 20:01:48 robin crmd[14139]:  warning: status_from_rc: Action 10 (pgsql_start_0) on robin failed (target: 0 vs. rc: 5): Error
Oct 29 20:01:48 robin crmd[14139]:  warning: update_failcount: Updating failcount for pgsql on robin after failed start: rc=5 (update=INFINITY, time=1414609308)
Oct 29 20:01:48 robin crmd[14139]:  warning: update_failcount: Updating failcount for pgsql on robin after failed start: rc=5 (update=INFINITY, time=1414609308)
Oct 29 20:01:48 robin pengine[14138]:  warning: unpack_rsc_op: Processing failed op start for pgsql:0 on robin: not installed (5)
Oct 29 20:01:48 robin pengine[14138]:  warning: common_apply_stickiness: Forcing msPostgresql away from robin after 1000000 failures (max=1)
Oct 29 20:01:48 robin pengine[14138]:  warning: common_apply_stickiness: Forcing msPostgresql away from robin after 1000000 failures (max=1)
```

I'm not very familiar with pacemaker and pgslq.Can someone help me or know my error? 
Maybe is there a solution to do an automated failback or reattach if master or slave node comes back?

Thanks a lot